# How can I pop out the large value one by one in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Just left the key who has the smallest value, I can't use  `min()` function.

Moving the code that OP tried from his comment: -

```
for i in key: 
    if dictionary[i]<dictionary[key]: 
        dictionary.pop(key) 
    elif dictionary[i]==dictionary[key]: 
        print (dictionary[i])
```

And the code from the other comment:

```
dictionary={'A': 3, 'B': -2, 'C': -1, 'D': -3} 
for key in dictionary: 
    print ("Keys and values>", key,end= '') 
    print (dictionary[key]) 
    print (dictionary) 
    for i in key: 
        if dictionary[i]<dictionary[key]: 
            dictionary.pop(key) 
        elif dictionary[i]==dictionary[key]: 
            print ("The minimum is",dictionary[i])
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. Post what you've done.

Comment: Any restriction on using the `sorted` function or `sort` method? **wink wink**

Comment: for i in key:
    if dictionary[i]<dictionary[key]:
        dictionary.pop(key)
    elif dictionary[i]==dictionary[key]:
        print (dictionary[i])

Comment: it is my homework, i think I am quite wrong with this one.

Comment: @user1718826.. Please post the code you tried in your question. Move it from comment.

Comment: dictionary={'A': 3, 'B': -2, 'C': -1, 'D': -3}
for key in dictionary:
    print ("Keys and values>", key,end= '')
    print (dictionary[key])

print (dictionary)
for i in key: 
    if dictionary[i]<dictionary[key]: 
        dictionary.pop(key) 
    elif dictionary[i]==dictionary[key]: 
        print ("The minimum is",dictionary[i])

Comment: You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13507914/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this. It uses `any` function to compare value of each key with all other values except its own. And if `any` value is found which is less that that value, then the `key` is popped.

```
>>> my_dict = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
>>> for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if any(value > value1 for key1, value1 in my_dict.items() if key1 != key):
            my_dict.pop(key)


3
4
>>> my_dict
{1: 2}
```

`any` function returns `True` if at least one value in the `list` passed to it is `True`.

**For e.g: -**

```
any([0, 0, False, True])   # Will print True
any([0, 0, False, False])  # Will print False
```

---

**UPDATE : -**

If you don't want to use `any` function, you can move the for loop of `any` function outside, and do the testing in that loop only: -

```
my_dict = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for key1, value1 in my_dict.items():

        if key1 != key and value > value1:
            my_dict.pop(key)

print my_dict
```

Comment: I never learned the "any" method. Can I use a loop to instead of this?

Comment: @user1718826.. Yeah you can use a loop. You can see that I have used a `for` loop in `any` function. Just move it outside, and do the testing inside it. You won't need any function there.

Comment: thank you, and how to avoid dictionary changed size during iteration?

Comment: @user1718826.. You would need to use a different dictionary. And move the smallest element in that dictionary. For that you need to change the code a little bit. I'll leave it to you to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict.items() to get the minimum-function.

```
my_dic = {...}
print min(my_dic.item(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
```